# Any suggestions on how to simplify this regex/replace/strip operation?

Tags: python, regex

This code, which is inside of a for loop, does what I need it to do:

```
string[i] = re.sub('^, |, $', '', string[i]).replace(', ,', ',').replace(',,', ',').rstrip(",")
```

It removes the extraneous commas, and space before/after commas, according to the patterns I specify.  But it's ugly as hell.  Any suggestions on how to simplify it, or at least make it more readable, would be greatly appreciated.

Basically looking to do the exact same thing as what I'm doing in this line of code, except more elegantly (if possible).

Many thanks!

Comment: example input output?

Comment: So on input `"a,,,,b"` you really want `"a,,b"` as output?  Are you sure? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to eliminate all spaces adjacent to commas, turn any number of adjacent commas into a single comma, and remove commas at the start and end of the string.

I suspect your current code doesn't actually do all of that perfectly (though it may work well enough for your actual data set).

Here's how I'd do it:

```
def clean_commas(text):
    return re.sub(r' *,[ ,]*', ',', text).strip(',')
```

The regexp turns any combination of spaces and commas (with at least one comma) into a single comma with no spaces around it. The `strip` call then removes any commas at the start or end of the result.

Example output:

```
>>> clean_commas("a,,,,b")
'a,b'
>>> clean_commas(" , ,a, b,,  , ,,  ,c,d  e , f  ,, ,") # spaces internal to "d  e" kept
'a,b,c,d  e,f'
```

It would even be possible to do this without any regular expressions, if you wanted:

```
def clean_commas(text):
    return ','.join(filter(None, (s.strip() for s in text.split(','))))
```

This first splits the input text by commas (which may result in some items that are empty strings, or strings of just whitespace). A generator expression then strips the whitespace from the beginning and end of each string. Then the `filter(None, ...)` call skips over any strings that are empty (you could achieve the same thing with an `if s.strip()` at the end of the the generator expression, but it seems silly to strip each string twice). Finally, the `','.join` call puts the output string together, with a single comma between each of the values.

Answer (score 1):

It's not *that* bad. It looks extra confusing because of commas in the search string.

For just the last part, `re.sub(r', ?,*', ',', string[i])` would get rid of the `,,` or `, ,` or `,,,,`, just not the commas at the beginning and the end...

```
>>> s = 'a,,,,b, ,c'
>>> re.sub(r', ?,*', ',', s)
'a,b,c'
```

Hmm, if you use `.strip(', ')` instead of `.rstrip()` it will get rid of all the commas at start and end, so...

```
 >>> s = ', a,,,,b, ,c, '
 >>> re.sub(r', ?,*', ',', s.strip(', ') )
 a,b,c
```